# Simplest way to deploy platform independent python apps with graphics functionality.

Tags: python

Let say I want to write a simple app that lets users paste in a column or two of data, click a few radio boxes and have my code process that data and display some plots for them. What are some of the best ways to develop and deploy this while taking into account the following considerations.

1) Cross platform. Runs on windows, mac, linux and has as few dependencies as possible as users may be unsophisticated. Preferably I wouldn't even want to require they have python installed (e.g. Windows users).

2) Python only (no C code), probably using Tkinter for GUI since it comes with Python.

3) Users may be concerned about privacy. Sending data over the web may be a show stopper. Ideally it runs locally.

Some options that come to mind are

1. Use SimPy plotting module. Box this all up together in one module somehow.
2. Make it run in the browser using Flask or Bottle. Maybe use javascript/jquery for plotting so it can run locally.
3. Deploy two versions using py2exe (or whatever it is called) to create a separate Windows executable and then deploy the python code to linux/mac.
4. Forget about python and just write it in java or javascript. Or use Jython?
5. Just make a webapp that runs on my own server. This gives me freedom to use any python modules (numpy, matplotlib etc) at the expense of privacy and ability to run locally (offline).

Can anyone offer some tips to developing and deploying these kind of apps? Thanks.

Comment: I've done a cross platform app recently. I used PyQt for the interface (it looks better than Tkinter). Then I used cx_Freeze (similar to py2exe) to bundle up all the dependencies for Windows and Mac, and InnoSetup to create a Windows installer (I later found cx_Freeze could do that as well). For Linux, I dived into Debian packaging to provide a PPA. It took a fair bit of my time to get all that working smoothly, but I'm satisfied that it's easy for users to install.

Comment: I don't understand why posts like this get marked as not constructive just because the answer might be subjective. Is there another place besides Stack Overflow that allows these kind of open ended, opinion-type questions?

Answer (score 2):

Two thought on your question.

1. Have you thought about building in using [pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/).  You could then package it for the desktop using [pyjamasdesktop](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyjamasDesktop) and get the best of both worlds. If you want to run it online you can, but if you want to make it available offline, it is a fairly simple transition. 
   The interface will be web based, so, you will not have access to all of the robustness of Tkinter.  However, you trade that for flexibility.
2. [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) will let you create packaging formats for both the mac and the windows platform. This way you do not have to learn two separate tools to package your application.